# Mongoose reference update

Tags: javascript, node.js, reference, mongoose

```
Kwizz.update({wachtwoord: req.body.password}, {teams: [req.session.loggedInTeamId]});
```

now it replaces the current teams in the Kwizz model - I just want to add 1 to the array.
Couldn't find a clear awnser, try my luck here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either [`$push`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray-push) or [`$addToSet`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray-addToSet):

```
Kwizz.update({ wachtwoord: req.body.password }, { $addToSet: { teams: 'req.session.loggedInTeamId' } }, function(err) {

    ...
});
```